# Encrypt parameters passed to a swf

Tags: actionscript-3, encryption, flash

does anyone know how to encrypt the parameters that are passed to a flash movie? The case is, that the user should not be able to read the parameters in the source code in plaintext.

And of course, I have to able to decrypt the parameter in actionscript 3 ;-)

thx,
tux

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look on the [AS3Crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) library ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, using the AS3Crypto library as above for example, but it only will stop causal snoopers. Anyone serious will be able to easily decrypt your parameters.

Just like DRM on audio and video, it must be possible for them to decrypt it in the same way your Flash applet is decrypting them.